# Service Reference - with EnableSession=true Session is null static value works fine

Tags: c#, session, web, service, reference

Problem: web service added as service reference returns static string fine but returns null when I get value from Session. I am using `[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]` to enable session state. Web service method test using URL works fine and returns correct results. But when I try to get value in a different project using service reference, it does not return session value.

Here is a detail, I have created a simple web service which returns a session value as a string in one ASP.NET C# 3.5 project. The web service code is as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for myWebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class myWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public myWebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        if (Session["UserName"] != null)
        {
            return Session["UserName"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "null ";
        }
    }

}
```

Using URL, it returns correct data

```
http://localhost:49942/MyProject/myWebService.asmx/HelloWorld
```

Here is the XML it returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">myusername@gmail.com</string>
```

In a different project (ASP.NET 3.5 C#) I have added this web service as a Service Reference. When I call its method it returns "null"

```
ServiceReference1.myWebServiceSoapClient sr = new ServiceReference1.myWebServiceSoapClient();
                string strValue = sr.HelloWorld();
```

If I return a static string value then it returns that string but Session shows as null.

I am sure I am missing something. Would you please help?

Comment: Just hear say, but have you tried enabling Asp.Net compatibility mode?

Comment: I didn't add it but i have added it now (<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>). I tried to add it in both projects one by one and same time as well but it didn't solve my problem. i tried to add the 'Web Reference' instead 'Service Reference' but the result is same.